# escape & in url

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

How can I escape `&` (ampersand) in url with the correct replacement in the jQuery function. 
I have tried

```
.replace("/&/g", "&amp;")  
.replace("/&/g", "%26") 
.replace("/&/g", "\&")
```

But nothing is working.

If anyone has idea please share with me.

Thanks

Comment: `.replace(/&/g, "%26")` should work if your JS is external. If it's embedded in your HTML, then you probably need to escape the `&` as `&amp;`. But, use `encodeURIComponent` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with jQuery - string replacement operations are plain old JavaScript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to just escape a URL, I recommend using a JavaScript function such as [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Answer (score 2):

Try the URLEncode plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/URLEncode

Comment: Really? Someone made a plugin for this?  Whats wrong with the standard JS function [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent)